# Image Animation with a Button WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation

I have an `image` within a `button`, I've wrote an `animation` that leads to `Grow` or `Shrink` When `IsMouseOver` Occurs, However I dont want the button itself `Grows` or `Shrinks` but the Image within the `Button` has to `Grow` or `Shrink`. Do you have any idea? I am all yours.

here is my **.XAML**

```
    <Button Margin="355,0,0,0" Width="100" Height="300" Click="Button_Click_1">
        <Image Source="img/blue.jpg" />
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.250" To="0" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.350" To="320" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.350" To="120" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.250" To="0" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="300" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="100" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply apply the `Style` to the `Image` instead of the `Button`.

```
<Button ...>
    <Image ...>
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <!-- You get the idea -->
```

Note that `Image` does not have a `Border` control, therefore you can't use the `BorderThickness` animation on the `Image`, you can instead apply this animation on the `Button` as you were doing before.

Also, your `Image` will require a `Height` in order to animate. Otherwise, you can use the `From` property on the `DoubleAnimation` like this:

```
<DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.350" From="300" To="320" 
                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give Height and Width to Image, else will get an Exception. As Mike said can't use BorderThickness.

```
<Button>
        <Image Source="Edit.png"  Height="50" Width="50">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!--<ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.250" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" />-->
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.350" To="320" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.350" To="120" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!--<ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.250" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" />-->
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="300" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="100" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try this

```
<Button Margin="355,0,0,0" Width="100" Height="300" Click="Button_Click_1">
            <Border Width="50" Height="150">
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.250" To="0" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.350" To="320" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.350" To="120" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.250" To="0" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="150" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="50" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Border.Style>
                <Image Source="MyImage.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Border>
        </Button>
```